# Database layer design with unit tests in mind

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Basically I need a bunch of database access interfaces that can be implemented differently, or to put it another way, de-coupled from the underlying actual database:

```
interface IDbConnexion
{
    IDbCollection Collection { get; }
    Task Connect();
}

interface IDbCollection
{
    void Insert(Model model);
}
```

I will use `Collection` to do CRUDs. But the problem with that is, for a concrete implementation for a particular database, eg MongoDB, I would need to do the following:

```
class MongoDbCollection: IDbCollection
{
    IMongoCollection<Model> _collection;

    void IDbCollection.Insert(Model model)
    {
        _collection.InsertOne(model);
    }
}
```

Because this is my own wrapper for the mongodb client, I would need to wrap every single method provided by `IMongoCollection` so that I can use its full power. Eg. if I wanna use `InsertMany` then I would need to add my own wrapper for `InsertMany` to `MongoDbCollection`. And as my need grows, `MongoDbCollection` will inflate too. But I don't wanna do this. I should just be able to access all the methods the mongodb driver exposes to me without too much extra work.

So I am thinking an alternative:

```
interface IDbConnexion
{
    IMongoCollection<Model> Collection { get; }
    ...
}
```

But the problem with this is that my interface is coupled with mongodb. My unit test mockup will need to implement `IMongoCollection` just for the sake of making it compile.

So my question is: is there a design pattern to allow me full access to the concrete `Collection` property while allowing me to easily change the concrete implementation.

Comment: This GitHub repo seems a bit old, but it may be worth a look https://github.com/RobThree/MongoRepository

Comment: @MattU Thanks for that link. I had a quick look at it. (Correct me if I am wrong) It uses the concrete `MongoRepository` for unit tests, not to mention the `IRepository` has the concrete `MongoCollection` as its collection property which seems like my 2nd solution whose downside I have mentioned in my main post.

Comment: Yeah. It isn't exactly what you need, that's why I only added it as a comment and not an answer. I just figured it may help you figure out a good way to do it. :P

Comment: @MattU No worries,. Thanks a lot!